# Accelerator not displayed in GtkCheckMenuItem

Tags: c, gtk3

I am currently fiddliny around with my menubar in GTK+3.
Until now I had some CheckMenuItems with a label and an accelerator shortcut displayed:

```
GtkWidget *create_menubar(void)
{
  GtkWidget *menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
  const static guint num_keys[] = {GDK_KEY_1, GDK_KEY_2, GDK_KEY_3, GDK_KEY_4, GDK_KEY_5, GDK_KEY_6, GDK_KEY_7, GDK_KEY_8, GDK_KEY_9, GDK_KEY_0};

  // Create a GtkAccelGroup and add it to the window.
  GtkAccelGroup *accel_group = gtk_accel_group_new();
  gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(window_main), accel_group);

  // submenu show colors
  GtkWidget *colors_Mi    = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("colors");
  GtkWidget *colors_Menu  = gtk_menu_new();

  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), colors_Mi);
  gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(colors_Mi), colors_Menu);

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLORS; i++)
  {
    char name[10];
    sprintf(name, "col %d", i+1);

// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< cut mark...
    GtkWidget *show_color_Mi = gtk_check_menu_item_new_with_label(name);
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< cut mark...

    gtk_check_menu_item_set_active(GTK_CHECK_MENU_ITEM(show_color_Mi), show_color[i]);
    if (i < 10)
    {
      gtk_widget_add_accelerator(show_color_Mi, "activate", accel_group, num_keys[i], GDK_MOD1_MASK, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
    }
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(colors_Menu), show_color_Mi);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(show_color_Mi), "toggled", G_CALLBACK(on_menu_show_colors_toggled), &show_color[i]);
  }
  return menubar;
}
```

This works fine so far.
The program displays several sets of data with a different color for each.
The entries in this menu are used to enable or disable a set of data.
Now I want to add some indication which set of data is drawn in which color.

To do this I changed creation of the MenuItem.
Now I create a horizontal box, where an image and a label is enclosed.

The lines between the cut marks (<<<<<<<<<<<<) are replaced with this:

```
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    GtkWidget *show_color_Mi = gtk_check_menu_item_new();

    GtkWidget *menubox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 2);
    GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new();
    GtkWidget *menulabel = gtk_label_new(name);

    cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, 20, 15);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, colors[i].r, colors[i].g, colors[i].b);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    gtk_image_set_from_surface(GTK_IMAGE(image), surface);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(show_color_Mi), menubox);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(menubox), image, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(menubox), menulabel, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Now I have CheckMenuItems which contain a colored rectangle and the same text as before my change. This is the good thing...

The bad thing is that for some reason the accelerator keys are not shown any longer.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong there?

Edit:

In updated according to José Fonte's answer and in general it works.
But in the meantime I found some other strange effect. I am running my program on some Ubuntu 14.04 machines with XFCE and it works as expected. I also run it in Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox and it works fine, too. But on another Ubuntu 14.04 machine in VmWare behaves different. The colored rectangles are missing but the accelerators are shown even when I use the incorrect label type. This is getting a bit weird...

Now I checked on which machine it works or not and which version of libgtk-3-bin is installed:

Ubuntu 16.04 (VirtualBox)
3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1  **OK**

Raspbian Jessie (Raspberry Pi)
3.14.5-1+deb8u1rpi1rpig  **OK**

Ubuntu 14.04, XFCE (native)
3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6  **OK**

Ubuntu 14.04, Unity (VmWare)
3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6  **FAIL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you are using a normal GtkLabel instead of GtkAccelLabel.

You must change to look like this:

```
[stuff deleted]
   ...
GtkWidget *menulabel = gtk_accel_label_new(name);
gtk_accel_label_set_accel_widget(GTK_ACCEL_LABEL(menulabel), show_color_Mi);
   ...
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(menubox), menulabel, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

Conclusion: Use an gtk_accel_label instead of a gtk_label, then set the accel widget which should be the menu item that contains it and change the fill and expand flags on gtk_box_pack_start to allow for extra space. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint! It really helped. But it causes some confusion as well. I was under the impression that the accelerator is a feature of the menu item and not of its enclosed elements. If I get it right I always need a label. If I just wanted the colored rectangles without any text, I would still need an accel_label to indicate the accelerator. That is a bit of a surprise for me...

Comment: You are right but if you want a textual representation of the accelerator then you will need a label, in this particular case, an accel_label.

Comment: In the meantime I found some other strange effect. I am running my program on some Ubuntu 14.04 machines with XFCE and it works as expected. I also run it in Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox and it works fine, too. But on another Ubuntu 14.04 machine in VmWare behaves different. The colored rectangles are missing but the accelerators are shown even when I use the incorrect label type. This is getting a bit weird...

Comment: Hmmm, maybe something related to the theme css. Check your vbox and give it homogeneous size, just as a test, to be sure you have space allocated to the image. Also check which versions of Gtk+ the distros are using.

Comment: Hi @Gerhardh, from the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAccelLabel.html): "Note that creating a GtkMenuItem with gtk_menu_item_new_with_label() (or one of the similar functions for GtkCheckMenuItem and GtkRadioMenuItem) automatically adds a GtkAccelLabel to the GtkMenuItem and calls gtk_accel_label_set_accel_widget() to set it up for you.". So, when you create the check_menu_item with label, an accell_label is created automatically and if you implement it then you must do it by yourself. Can't see how that happens with a normal label. The code is correct?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make much sense. But my colleague showed me the result with the same Git commit ID that I had just pushed before and this was before I got your hint with the accellabel. I will check what is going on when I am back in office after Easter.